# how to use git pull with GitPython?

Tags: python, git, git-pull, gitpython, pygit2

I am trying to pull filesfrom git using python but it's not working. Below is the code I was using:

```
import git 
git.cmd.Git().pull('https://github.com/User/repo','master')
```

it asks for authentication and after that terminates.

Could someone please help me here? what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is to create a `git.Repo` object to represent your repository.

```
from git import Repo

# rorepo is a Repo instance pointing to the git-python repository.
# For all you know, the first argument to Repo is a path to the repository
# you want to work with
repo = Repo(self.rorepo.working_tree_dir)
assert not repo.bare
```

In the above example, the directory `self.rorepo.working_tree_dir` equals `/Users/mtrier/Development/git-python` and is my working repository which contains the `.git` directory. You can also initialize `GitPython` with a bare repository.

This is what you asked for :

```
 repo = git.Repo('repo_name')
 o = repo.remotes.origin
 o.pull()
```

Comment: I got attribute error: IterableList has no attribute origin

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS but you should use a [credential helper](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) in order to cache the password (or [token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) if you have [2FA activated](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa)) in it.

This is assuming your are trying to pull from a private repository.

On Windows, for example, that would be "`manager`", and you can cache your credentials with [`git credential fill`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential#_typical_use_of_git_credential).

Comment: Yes, but after providing credentials it should git pull but I’m unable to see any change in my folder

Comment: @ZZ3111 Then test it with git directly to see if the same issue occurs.